# Is razor has nothing to do with the type of template?

Tags: templates, razor

I am a beginner in web design(C# - MVC - Razor).
I need a template for admin panel.
What is different between templates(wordpress or joomla or html or php or ... )?
Is razor has nothing to do with the type of template?
What type of template is best for me?
What I search for a template model?
I'm confused. help please.
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any template will and can work, you just have to manually port over the structure to match (ex. by default some templates have their javascript stored in a folder structure called "js" but MVC framework has theirs under the folder "scripts") . The easiest templates I've found to convert over can be found by using the search term "bootstrap themes" The "one page" themes are especially easy to port over.

To be honest, all you really need to understand is basic css, js mappings along with how the layout pages/BundleConfig work in .Net MVC.

As far as admin panels, these convert over with relative ease:
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/
https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S

Comment: But I mean 
in template, For example, for the textbox     
<input type="text" id="form-field-1" placeholder="Username" />     
but in Razor     
@html.textboxfor(x => x.name)    
Which should be used?    And for more complex elements like grids was harder work

Comment: You will be converting it over to the razor syntax. Believe it or not, the more complex things you have (like grids, insane arrays being fed into jquery UI libraries) the easier it actually is to build your site on a fully OOP platform. Honestly, (not saying this in a bad way or anything as I came from a php background myself and it didn't start clicking until I was exposed more to a OOP way of doing things) but you need to go through  a few more of the MVC tutorials to gain a better understanding on the what and why because a comment box on SO will never be enough to explain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help